# How are elliptic curves designed for encryption purpose?

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design

Why can't we use any random elliptic curve? What are the properties that need to be satisfied?

Comment: Can you propose a procedure to pick "randomly" an elliptic curve?

Comment: That's a complex subject. Useful references: [safecurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/index.html), [Brainpool requirements](https://web.archive.org/web/20170918080408/http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/20141001_ECCBrainpool_PositionPaper.pdf), [sec2 §2.1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsection.2.1).

Comment: Far from being the only reason, but some curves can be implemented more efficiently than others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is necessary for generating an elliptic curve?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34563/what-is-necessary-for-generating-an-elliptic-curve)